# Number Formatting in Mvc TextBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'd like to add a textbox in mvc that is 6 characters wide,  with a decimal after 3 digits Like xxx.xx
How can I do this. I am trying to do something like this but it is not giving desired output. Please share 
with me to sort this out. Thank You.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Axis1_Amount, new { maxlength = "6" })
  $('#Amount').blur(function () {
            myFunction(this.value);
        });
        function myFunction(val) {
            getVal = parseFloat(Math.round(val * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            $("#Amount").val(getVal);
        }
```

Comment: What is actual result

Comment: Above code just appends .00 after any number I type in textbox. Like I have typed 555555. It gives output 555555.00 but I want the output to be 555.55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function myFunction(val) {
        getVal = parseFloat(Math.round(val) / 100).toFixed(2);
        $("#Amount").val(getVal);
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E2K2D/)

Comment: It is returning me the required output when I alert the value. but in textbox it is not showing the value with decimal . How can I resolve this?

Comment: @Sandy Can you set the fiddle

Comment: Sir, after entering this value 5555 in textbox, it is giving me output:55.55 but it should give 555.5 . Any number entered in textbox should give decimal after three digits

Answer (score 0):

As I am having a condition that my textbox will not contain more than 6 characters and referencing above given answer, I am solved my problem

```
  function FormatString(val) {
            getVal = 0;
            // getVal = parseFloat(Math.round(val) / 100).toFixed(2);
            if (val.length <= 3) {
                getVal = parseFloat(Math.round(val)).toFixed(2);
            }
            else if (val.length == 4) {
                getVal = parseFloat(Math.round(val) / 10).toFixed(2);
            }
            else if (val.length == 5) {
                getVal = parseFloat(Math.round(val) / 100).toFixed(2);
            }
            else if (val.length == 6) {
                getVal = parseFloat(Math.round(val) / 1000).toFixed(2);
            }
            $("#Amount").val(getVal);
        }
```